# Why is it called a time series and not a time sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, time-series

A sequence is defined as a function from ℕ to ℝ which assigns each natural number  a real number a. A series is is defined as the sequence of partial sums of the sequence of real numbers (a). A time series is commonly defined as a sequence of values ordered in time. If that's the case, why is it called a "time series" and not a "time sequence?

Comment: Probably some obscure historical reason -- maybe the term was not first used by mathematicians

Comment: It's a series in the colloquial sense (as in, a sequence!); I expect the term was not invented by mathematicians. Maybe actuaries or quants or something?